# issue with returning on my library system

Tags: java, return, system, bluej

I have added a return feature to my library system, which successfully works. The problem is that, when you go to take out a book after returning one, it's unsuccessful, and states "the book is already borrowed". I am struggling on how to fix this issue.

This is my code for the 'borrowing book' and 'return book' of my system...

```
public String borrowBook(String titleBorrow) 
{
    int found = 0;
    String bookFound = "\n";
    for (Book b : collection) 
    {
        if (b.getTitle().equals(titleBorrow)) 
        {
            if (found == 0) 
            {
                found = 1;
            }
            if (!b.isBorrowed()) 
            {
                if (b.numcopies > 0)
                {found = 2;
                    b.numcopies -=1;
                    break;
                }else 
                {
                    found = 1;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    if (found == 0) {
        bookFound="Sorry, this book is not in our catalog.";
    } else if (found == 1) {
        bookFound="Sorry, this book is already borrowed.";
    } else if (found == 2) {
        bookFound="You successfully borrowed ";      
    }   

    return bookFound; 

}
public String returnBook(String returnedBook)
{
     int found = 0;
     boolean borrowed = false;
    String bookreturn = "\n";
    for (Book b : collection)
            {
        if (b.getTitle().equals(returnedBook)) 
        {
            if (found == 0) 
            {
                found = 1;
            }
            if (!b.isBorrowed()) 
            {
                b.borrowed=true;
                found = 2;
                b.numcopies +=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (found == 0) {
        bookreturn="Sorry, this book is not in our catalog.";
    } else if (found == 1) {
        bookreturn="Please try again.";
    } else if (found == 2) {
        bookreturn="You successfully returned the book ";      
    }   

    return bookreturn; 

}
}
```

Comment: where is borrow book code?

Comment: Sorry about that, that's it up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your borrow the book, you should set the borrow flag like:

```
 if (!b.isBorrowed()) {
    b.borrowed = true;
    ..
```

While when you return the book, you should,

```
if (!b.isBorrowed()) {
     b.borrowed=false;//its returned now and can be borrowed
```

You could extend the logic with number of copies of same book that you have in library.